# поменять join местами (MS SQL)

Tags: sql, join

Всем привет, у меня есть следующий запрос:

```
select planzp.unplanzp, planzp.ceh, planzp.kzajnpp, planzp.kmat, planzp.undoc, planzp.ntechpr, kum.edi, kum.edi2, kum.kssm, kumk.bs, planzp.kprt, planzp.kol, planzp.npp, planzp.summa, planzp.rcentr 
from planzp 
left join kumk on (planzp.kmat = kumk.kmat) and (planzp.kzajnpp = kumk.kzaj) and (planzp.ceh = kumk.ceh) 
and (planzp.kprt = kumk.kprt) 
left join kum on kum.unkum = kumk.unkum 
where planzp.ceh not IN (102, 105, 107, 108, 10807, 10707, 10210, 10230, 10519, 10731, 10730, 10504, 10201, 10733, 10501, 10215) 
and kzajnpp not in ('СН') and (planzp.kmat LIKE 'П%' or planzp.kmat LIKE 'Н%')  and planzp.kol > 0 and kum.kssm not IN ('МС02')
```

но мне нужно сперва заджойнить таблицы kum и kumk, а потом planzp и kumk(поменять джойны местами в текущем запросе), как мне это правильно сделать? если я меняю джойны местами то выходит ошибка "The multi-part identifier "kumk.unkum" could not be bound."

Comment: Порядок join ни как не влияет на результат. для чего вы хотите это сделать ? А так то в условии on любого join доступны колонки таблиц которые появились ранее в запросе. Так что единственный путь менять местами join, менять условия в on. Но тогда встает вопрос, если вы их поменяете местами, то по какому полю kumk можно будет соединить с planzp (ибо других таблиц в запросе более нет)

Comment: kumk с planzp по полям kmat, ceh, kprt надо бы джойнить,
а почему тогда выходит ошибка если я просто даже местами джойны меняю? если в принципе разницы в порядке джойна нет

Comment: нет разницы в результатах запроса, если перестановка не изменяет доступность таблиц и это не приводит к синтаксической ошибке, как у вас

Comment: А в kum есть эти поля ? (kmat, ceh, kprt) Если да, то просто имена таблиц измените, а on оставьте на месте, что бы kum по своему on ссылался только на planzp, а kumk уже на него по unkum

Comment: в kum этих полей как раз таки нет( kum с kumk джойнится только по полю unkum, наверно в этом вся проблема т.к. kum с planzp не джойнится никак

Comment: Оба Ваши джойна - на самом деле INNER, а вовсе не LEFT. Скажите спасибо условию `and kum.kssm not IN ('МС02')`.

Comment: @thegamestarted А тогда с какой целью вы пытаетесь поменять их местами, если это логически невозможно ?

Comment: @Mike как я понял, выходит не совсем верный результат на конце, якобы сперва нужно провести соединения kum и kumk, а уже затем kumk и planzp

Comment: А почему вы так подумали. left подразумевают что в указанных таблицах значений может и не быть и это считается нормальным для результата. Если planzp может не быть для данных kum, kumk то да, возможно надо менять порядок. Вы бы описали чего именно вы пытаетесь достичь, а не как вы это пытаетесь сделать. Очень может быть, что проблема в том, что указал Akina, то что left теряют смысл из за where

Comment: @Mike да, конечно, я не прошёл мимо комментария Akina и изменил left на inner. Я пытаюсь получить строки из таблицы planzp именно по такому условию, которое у меня прописано после where. Проблема в том, что, на выходе некоторые строки дублируются (получается две абсолютно одинаковые строки), хотя в таблице planzp это одна строка с данным условием ...

Comment: если строки дублируются, значит на эту одну строку из planzp нашлось две подходящие строки в kumk или kum. выведите скажем id из этих таблиц и посмотрите что лишнее, потом подумайте над условием которое бы дало из них только нужную строку. И порядок join тут точно не причем

Answer (score 0):

Мне подсказали, все было до безобразия просто, вместо planzp надо было поставить kum после from и ошибка ушла

```
select planzp.unplanzp, planzp.ceh, planzp.kzajnpp, planzp.kmat, planzp.undoc, planzp.ntechpr, kum.edi, kum.edi2, kum.kssm, kumk.bs, planzp.kprt, planzp.kol, planzp.npp, planzp.summa, planzp.rcentr 
from kum 
join kumk on kum.unkum = kumk.unkum 
join planzp on (planzp.kmat = kumk.kmat) and (planzp.kzajnpp = kumk.kzaj) and (planzp.ceh = kumk.ceh) and (planzp.kprt = kumk.kprt) 
where planzp.ceh not IN (102, 105, 107, 108, 10807, 10707, 10210, 10230, 10519, 10731, 10730, 10504, 10201, 10733, 10501, 10215) 
and kzajnpp not in ('СН') and (planzp.kmat LIKE 'П%' or planzp.kmat LIKE 'Н%')  and planzp.kol > 0 and kum.kssm not IN ('МС02')
```